# How to start with entity framework and service oriented architecture?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

At work I need to create a new web application, that will connect to an MySql Database.
(So far I only have expercience with Linq-To-Sql classes and MSSQL servers.)

My superior tells me to use the entity framework (he probably refers to Linq-To-Entity) and provide everything as a service based architecture. Unfortunately nobody at work has experience with that framework nor with a real nice server oriented architecture. This speficic project I'm leading will be long-term, meaning multiple years, so it would be best to design it the way, that multiple target plattforms like asp.net, c# wpf, ... could use it)
For now, the main target plattform is ASP.net

So I do have the following questions:
**1**) Where can I read best what's really behind service oriented architecture (but for now beginner tutorials work fine as well) and how to use it in best practise?
**2**) So far I can't see a real difference between Linq-To-Sql classes and the information I've googled so far on the 'entity framework'. So, whats the difference? Where do I find nice tutorials for it?
**3**) Is there any difference in the entity framework regarding the database server (MSSQL or MySQL)? If not, does that mean that code snipperts I will stumble across will word database independent?
**4**) I do use Visual Studio 2010. Do I have to regard something specific?

Comment: The name of the framework is actually the Entity Framework.  Linq to Entities is just the Linq extensions used by/for EF.  And none of this has any connection to SOA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that this is meant to be as painless as possible.

1. Generate your entity model from source database(s)
2. Publish using .Net Data Service
3. Write client components to subscribe to the Data Service

I could explain how ll this works but i feel its best to let the experts say it all ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx

Sounds like a great project, good luck with it :)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Because im new and have no rep yet i ould only post 1 link ...

Here's another that you should find really helpful ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336128.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Also on the MSDN site are a great series of videos by Julie Lerman on EF 4.0

[Videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc300162.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the microsoft white papers? For example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx).

If I were leading a team on a project that size though I'd be looking to pick up some good books, and I'd be asking my employer to pay for them. Get on Amazon and see what has good reviews. There's only so much you can pick up from the internet imho.